# TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing thrown on second instance of this query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg

So I am building a query based on user input in flask with this code:

```
    if empty_indic_form.validate_on_submit():
    query='select name, year, value, display_name from literal inner join ent on ent_id=ent.id where display_name in ('
    for i in indic_form.indicators.data:
        query=query+'\''+i+'\','
    query=query[:-1]+') '
    query=query+'and name in ('
    for c in order_c:
        query=query+c+','
    query=query[:-1]+')'
    data_return=db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

I have confirmed that query looks like what it is supposed to, and even had an earlier session where it was returning a list of rowproxy objects like I was expecting. But now I am getting this error no matter what I do!

I have set query to a variable in the templates so I can print it out, and here is what I get:

> `select name, year, value, display_name from literal 
>   inner join ent 
>   on ent_id=ent.id 
>   where display_name in ('Energy savings of primary energy (TJ)','Adolescent birth rate (women aged 15-19 years)','Net migration rate','Transmission and distribution losses (%)') 
>   and name in ('Burkina Faso', 'Ghana', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Pakistan')`

I ran that directly on my Postgres DB and the result was grand.

In the error dump I notice that the `data_return=db.engine.execute(query).fetchall()` line is building with an empty dictionary as the parameters, which of course throws that error in the end. Can I force it not to do this? The query object looks like it does above, whats wrong with it now? Should I perhaps be killing the db session upon refreshing the page or going to the home page?

Comment: dumping at the db.engine.execute stack trace line I get 

`
`"query= 
u'select name, year, value, display_name from literal inner join ent on ent_id=ent.id where display_name in ('Old-age dependency ratio, ages 65 and older','Forest area (% of total land area)','Energy intensity of transportation sector (MJ/2011 USD PPP)','Divisia Decomposition Analysis - Energy Intensity component Index','HDI: Average annual growth rate, 2000-2013','GDI: Expected years of schooling, males') and name in ('Saudi Arabia', 'Pakistan', 'Finland', 'Jamaica')"  "`


so Ill try coercing from unicode to str?

Comment: Not really familiar, but for psycopg2 the normal query is using triple quoted literals. Have you tried that?

Comment: Where the full traceback message?

Comment: [Mom of little Robert wants to have a word with you.](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: got a great answer but can someone please explain why this was down voted? I am a very new coder and while I know sql injections are serious threats I didnt know string concatenation makes them this easy, not sure how I would have inferred that from the other questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The fundamental error in your method is using string concatenation to build an SQL query. If `indic_form.indicators.data` or `order_c` is user provided data, for example from an HTTP request, you've probably opened yourself up for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The error

```
TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing
```

is the result of this concatenation: your query string contains a rogue `"%"`, which is part of the placeholder syntax of [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/) – the DB-API usually used with SQLAlchemy to talk to Postgresql. This is exactly the reason why manual concatenation should not be done. Getting escaping right can be hard.

Passing a list of values to `IN` operator is done using [tuples adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation) in Psycopg2. In SQLAlchemy you'd use the [`in_`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_) column operator, or an [expanding bind param](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_) that were [introduced in version 1.2](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_12.html#change-3953).

Unfortunately in your particular case the SQLAlchemy wrapping, the engine, has a gotcha: as all your arguments would be tuples, the SQLAlchemy engine thinks that you're trying to pass it an iterable of argument tuples as [multiparams](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute.params.*multiparams/**params) and uses `executemany()` automatically. You can work around this by using the [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct, which allows for DB-API agnostic bound parameter syntax and dictionaries as argument containers:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

...

if empty_indic_form.validate_on_submit():
    # Note that the placeholders shouldn't have enclosing parentheses
    query = """SELECT name, year, value, display_name
               FROM literal
               INNER JOIN ent ON ent_id = ent.id
               WHERE display_name IN :display_name
                 AND name IN :name"""

    data_return = db.engine.execute(
        text(query), {'display_name': tuple(indic_form.indicators.data),
                      'name': tuple(order_c)}).fetchall()
```

To recap: never build SQL queries using string concatenation or manual formatting. Always use placeholders / bound parameters.

Comment: this is awsome, thanks! I am having a hard time navgating sql alchemy's documentation, where can I see more about Placeholders/bounds?

Comment: Im also now getting this

`File "C:\Users\Vince\Google Drive\PeacefulMandE\Vasco de Data\Vasco\views.py", line 66, in show_avail
{'display_name': tuple(indic_form.indicators.data),
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: Prolly `indic_form.indicators.data` is `None`. Just handle that special case the way that suits you best. For more info on using textual SQL with SQLAlchemy, read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql

Comment: Or if I run the code as copied "text is not defined"

Comment: Remember to add the import.

Comment: Update on this many years later - can you use f strings/is that a good idea?

Comment: Looks like you can with a little finesse? https://github.com/arogozhnikov/python3_with_pleasure/issues/3

Comment: It is not a good idea, as demonstrated in that issue. It is just another form of string concatenation/formatting. If by finesse you mean using `!r`, then that's neither safe nor practical: it will break with strings that contain a `'`.