# sql Check if column is substring of another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to check one column substring is in another columns

**table1**

```
FullName              
Johns Doue               
Johnny                   
Betty Smith, Chair
```

**table2**

```
Name       
John
```

using table2 to see if it is a substring of table1. it should return Johns Doue and Johnny.

```
SELECT * FROM table1.FullName AS table1      
JOIN table2.Name AS table2    
WHERE table2.Name LIKE SUBSTRING(table1.FullName, 0, 10);
```

this is returning null's being compared. im not sure what i am doing wrong. From my logic, it seems like its taking the results from table2.name and comparing to the substrings of table1.FullName.

Answer (score 18):

You need to put wildcards in the `LIKE` pattern to make it look for substrings. You also seem to be confusing table and column names in your `SELECT` syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
WHERE t1.FullName LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.Name, '%')
```

You can also use `LOCATE` instead of `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
WHERE LOCATE(t2.Name, t1.FullName) > 0
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/738daa/2)

Comment: i did the first query but the t2.name resulting a null

Comment: I added a demo showing that both queries work with your sample data.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option using a `join` with `like` and `concat`:

```
select * 
from table1 as t1
    join table2 as t2 on t1.FullName like concat('%',t2.name,'%')
```

If you only want full names that start with the name, then remove the first `'%'`.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53afe0/1)

Comment: I have already done that but its still giving me a results of an empty string thats compared to another empty string.

Comment: or there is something populated in the t1.fullname but its being compared with t2.name and t2.name is null.


**fullname**     
john doue      

**name**     
(empty)

Comment: @user2113896 -- guessing here a little, but what about just adding `where` criteria to eliminate blank values?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/290973/2

Comment: yeah i added a statement where it checks if its not null but doesnt work.

Comment: @user2113896 -- at this point, you need to clarify your question... did you try the working fiddle?  can you replicate the issue you are having in it and repost the link to the one that doesn't work correctly?

Comment: actually yeah it worked. i dont know why it wasnt before. but thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

`LOCATE` is not available in some SQL flavours (e.g. Postgres) and apparently using string concatenation to build a SQL query is frowned upon (source: [TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090730/typeerror-dict-object-does-not-support-indexing-thrown-on-second-instance-of)).

You could alternatively use the `POSITION` command:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
WHERE POSITION(t2.Name IN t1.FullName) > 0
```