# Issue executing SQL file with SQLAlchemy engine - using % in a like condition

Tags: sql, python-2.7

I'm using a simple Python function to run a SQL file (still using Python 2.7).

Relevant parts of the function used:

```
sql_query = read_file(file_path)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection)
engine.execute(sql_query)
```

When running, I get this error

> TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing

After looking it up I found this :
[TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing thrown on second instance of this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090730/typeerror-dict-object-does-not-support-indexing-thrown-on-second-instance-of)

and in the SQL query, I am using a condition of `LIKE '%abc%'`. Is there any way to solve this without having to change my SQL query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Textual SQL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) to tell SQLAlchemy to treat the string as raw SQL.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

sql_query = read_file(file_path)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection)
engine.execute(text(sql_query))
```